# How do I get the current date in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, date, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've found a couple references online, but nothing that works with vanilla XSLT 1.0.

Is there a reasonable way without extension methods/parameters to get the current year in an XSLT?

EDIT:

For other's reference, I used XSL Arguments to make this happen.  .NET doesn't really have XSLT 2.0 support, so I ended up using params.

```
xslArg.AddParam("CurrentYear", "", DateTime.Now.Year);

<xsl:param name="CurrentYear"/>

<xsl:value-of select="$CurrentYear"/>
```

Comment: There are two very good XSLT 2.0 processors available on .NET. They don't come from Microsoft, is that what's holding you back?

Comment: @MichaelKay I would prefer to use only the built-in stuff, but if you have links for me, I'd love to know!

Comment: Microsoft stopped development on most of their XML infrastructure years ago, so you should really look at third parties. Saxon and XmlPrime both have XSLT 2.0 solutions for .NET which are widely used. I'm responsible for Saxon so that would be my recommendation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no standard way to get the current date-time in XSLT 1.0.

You need some kind of extension.